# How to implement a persistent (non-refreshing) page element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would be the best approcah to have a div containg a flash player, that does not refresh when you mavigate to another page on the same site. This would mean the player would not stop. I have 2 examples:

The first is http://www.djtunes.com/ unfortunately this adds a # to the url and all navigation after invoking the player is appended to the the site url with the # in between.

The second example is http://hypem.com/ this constructs the url in a more friendly fashion. I have noticed that clicking the refresh button reloads the entire page but this is to be expected. Any assistance with this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: looks like you are looking for ajax solution am i right? google jquery ajax... if you do not understand im sure there are loads of videos for tutorials on how it works

Comment: You can't reload a container window without reloading the stuff inside it, but you may be able to stuff all the navigation elements in an iFrame (not pretty), or refresh them with asynchronous Javacript (worse). I don't entirely understand what you're trying to achieve though.

Comment: I am trying to achieve exactly what they have implemented on [link]http://hypem.com I think everything inside the content-wrapper div is refreshed using ajax. What would be the negatives of using such a method? Do you think this would affect google analytics in any way?

Comment: hi @ejey, did you solve your problem? I am looking for a solution too but unfortunately without good results ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770490/how-to-keep-elements-non-refreshed

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll require ajax to load the rest of the pages, with the flash player running. To get the URLs like hypem.com, you can try [manipulating the browser history. Read up on this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)